# How do you route to an action within controller by a parameter value

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have such requests:

```
   /api/roove?request=wager
```

The request parameter value changes each time.

I have 5 different actions that are determined by that parameter value.

I need to route based on that value.

How can that be achieved.

I want to be able to use this:

```
[Route("api/roove?request=wager")]
```

on every action. But an error is thrown if I use symbols like '?'.

I dont want to use a custom parameter value.

Comment: Show your code, how did you try? and what error are you getting?

Comment: I dont have a code. I dont know how to route by parameter.